# ImageMagick: redraw a text without "-draw" for only outward stroke

Tags: imagemagick, stroke

I try to create a text image with ImageMagick, where is the stroke expands only outward. [I found a solution](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/#stroke), where I should use the "-draw" command, but with it I would need the size of my image, but I don't know it in advance.

The command below should be upgrated. Somehow I would need to draw the text again on it, without strokewidth:

```
convert -background none -fill white -pointsize 100 -stroke red \
        -strokewidth 20 label:text stroke.png
```

@leu's solution almost good, but the positioning of the new text isn't in the good position. My result was that above, and I don't know, where I took a mistake:

[image]

Comment: I have read your question many, many times (and the answer) and I still have no idea what you mean. Can you try and better explain what an *"outward stroke"* is please? And what exactly is wrong with the answer by leu?

Comment: OK, my goal is, if I add a stroke to the text, I want to see the original text, and the border only outside of the text. So the border should let the whole original text visible, only add the border out of it.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion: combine `label:"Some text"` with `-annotate "Some text"`. Like this:

```
#myfont="Arial-Black-Standard"
#myfont="Tahoma"
#offset="-0-0"
#offset="-20-10"
#offset="-30-10"
#offset="-10+10"

myfont="Tahoma"
offset="+10+10"

convert -respect-parentheses \
     \(                      \
        -font "${myfont}"    \
        -pointsize 180       \
        -strokewidth 18      \
        -fill blue           \
        -stroke blue         \
        -background none     \
         label:"Test text"   \
     \)                      \
     -gravity center         \
     -font "${myfont}"       \
     -pointsize 180          \
     -fill white             \
     -annotate "${offset}" "Test text" \
      result${offset}.png
```

Play with the `offset=...` variable (also with the point sizes and stroke widths) to get closer to what you want. Here are some of my results:

[image]

However, like @MarkSetchell, I do not fully comprehend what you want to achieve. An explanation of what you mean by *"outward stroke"* that ***I*** do understand is missing...

Answer (score 0):

yes: draw the same text onto your pic - maybe by piping output of your command to another convert

```
convert -background none -fill white -pointsize 100 -stroke red \
        -strokewidth 20 label:text png:- \
| convert -fill white -pointsize 100 -stroke none \
          -draw 'text 10,82 "text"' - stroke.png
```

the trick is to correctly place the second string. x-position is half the strokewidth, but y-position seems to be font- and pointsize-dependant. My approach was to first place both strings over each other when strokewidth was set to 0:

```
 convert -background none -fill white -pointsize 100 -stroke red \
         -strokewidth 0 label:text png:- \
 | convert -fill white -pointsize 100 -stroke none \
           -draw 'text 0,72 "text"' - stroke.png
```

then you have to add half the strokewidth to this y-position as well.

a bit of trial-and-error to get the correct y-position, but it seems to work for any string.

**== edit ==**

of course, we don't need to do trial-and-error. But instead we can use ImageMagick's power. Just perform the following steps (in this example within Bash):

```
#!/bin/bash

# read text from command line (or use "Test Text")
text=${1:-"Test Text"}
# strokewidth
sw=20
# pointsize
ps=120
# font
font=Arial
# result file
result="stroke.png"

# do some calc
sw_half=$(expr $sw / 2)

convert -background none -font $font -fill white -pointsize $ps -stroke red -strokewidth $sw label:"$text" $result
convert -background none -font $font -fill white -pointsize $ps -stroke none label:"$text" png:- | composite -geometry +${sw_half}+${sw_half} - $result $result
```

You can get the list of fonts available on your system by

```
convert -list font
```

The idea is the same as above: draw the text twice and draw one onto the other while using an offset of half the strokewidth.

The results all look like the following

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the result isn't enought exact, the second text shifted to right from the expected position.